# How to save images to a server folder via sockets using python and opencv?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, opencv

I would like to know how to save images captured by Opencv, in a directory created by code that should stay on the server ...**

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
haar_file = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
datasets = 'datasets'  #All the faces data will be present this folder
sub_data = raw_input ('digite o seu nome')     #These are sub data sets of folder, for my faces I've used my name

path = os.path.join(datasets, sub_data)
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
(width, height) = (130, 100)    # defining the size of images 


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_file)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #'0' is use for my webcam, if you've any other camera attached use '1' like this

# The program loops until it has 100 images of the face.
count = 1
while count < 101: 
    (_, im) = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 4)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height))
        cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.png' % (path,count), face_resize)
    count += 1

    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', im)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Huh? Why must your code stay on a server? What server? What have sockets got to do with it? Your question risks being closed if you don't clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Carlos You can save images simply using `cv2.imwrite('final_image.jpg', img)
`